# Save blob string to mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob

I'm trying to insert a string into a blob data type field with utf-8 encoding.

All the examples I could find were about storing an image, not string.

Here's what I tried:

```
Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("db").ConnectionString)
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("proc_name", con)
            cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_description", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(description))  
            ...    
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
...
```

mysql:

```
 select convert(description using hebrew) from tableA where id=123;
    returns: ????????? ???? ??? ?????? ????? ???? ????. ??? ????? ???? ???, ??? ?? ????.
```

(existing records in the table return fine with this conversion, only new records are the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future programmers who might come across this, the problem was environmental, it only happend in the workbench window, the storing of the data was fine.